# How to Deal with Talkative Training Partner

Tags: etiquette, social

What is a good way to stop people from talking to me & correcting little flaws in my technique when I'm trying to concentrate on fixing larger flaws in my technique?

I know that some gyms don't allow talking. & instructors can do a pretty good job of keeping those who like to chat in line.

Should I not talk back to the talkative partner?
Ask them to not talk?

I want to say "Please be quiet, I've got this & your interruptions are making me lose my concentration."

Some training partners are great, & know *when* to interject. But I feel like some are trying to show off their knowledge at an inopportune time.

This might be a little opinion-based, but I'd really like some input from others who have been in the same situation.

> For the record, I genuinely enjoy the conversation of my training partners. I don't want anyone reading this & thinking I don't want their input.

Comment: I think your edited comment is fine. For every thing, there is a season.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quite frankly, yes, that's basically exactly what you do, ask them to stop giving you advice. If you want to be nice about it, thank them, but say that you really need to concentrate, and the talking is distracting you.

Comment: I agree, that's the most practical approach. And making sure to not talk too much myself. I think keeping a mouthguard in might help too.

Answer (score -1):

I have training BJJ over the last five years. In this period I have met all kinds of personalities on the mats. That is part of it, deal with cool people, deal with unpleasant people. It is like that in all parts of life.

Answer (score -4):

1. He might suffer from ADHD syndrom. You need talk with him after coffee.
2. If not, he may lack daily default conversation. Men's daily required talking volume is A4 7 pages.
3. If you want to talk with him seriously, please meet in the late afternoon and after  a few cups of coffee break.

Comment: This misses the point - the OP is asking about how to avoid conversation during class - such that they can focus on their technique and training.

Comment: I hadn't heard that about a daily talking volume. Thanks for the info Tommy!

Comment: I think that is a good advice